# How to import shared libraries in Cmake for Android

Tags: java, android, qt, cmake

I have been trying to import a project for Android using CMake but when I try to import these libraries and compile and execute the program on Andorid using terminal, I get the following error:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 6162): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162): Process: org.abc.project, PID: 6162
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162): **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libcsoundandroid.so" not found**
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6162):    at org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.loadApp
```

My *CMakeLists.txt* is:

```
add_library(csoundandroid SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET csoundandroid PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/ayush/csound-android-6.07.0/CsoundForAndroid/CsoundAndroid/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/)

add_library(sndfile SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sndfile PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/ayush/csound-android-6.07.0/CsoundForAndroid/CsoundAndroid/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/)

add_library(c++_shared SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET c++_shared PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/ayush/csound-android-6.07.0/CsoundForAndroid/CsoundAndroid/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/)
set(LIBS1 libcsoundandroid.so)
set(LIBS2 libsndfile.so)
set(LIBS3 libc++_shared.so)
link_directories(/home/ayush/csound-android-6.07.0/CsoundForAndroid/CsoundAndroid/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi)

include_directories(/home/ayush/csound/include)
include_directories(/home/ayush/csound/android/CsoundAndroid/jni/)
target_link_libraries(abc ${LIBS1} ${LIBS2} ${LIBS3} )
```

Here *abc* is the executable file generated. All my libraries listed there are at the same place. Could you help me find out what the error is? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Property *IMPORTED_LOCATION* should contain full path to the library file. This is explicitely written in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) for that property.

For link with imported library, use **target name**, not a library file:

```
# Correctly set property for imported library
set_property(TARGET csoundandroid PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /home/ayush/csound-android-6.07.0/(...)/armeabi/libcsoundandroid.so
)

# And correctly link with it
set(LIBS1 csoundandroid)

target_link_libraries(abc ${LIBS1})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was also able to do it using add_library. I will give the above solution a try too :)